# How to set default value while insert null value into not null column SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, ssms, default

I have two tables `t1` and `t2`. Both have `id` and `name` columns. The name column of `t1` is defined as not null and it has the default value of 'Peter'.

I want to insert all the values from `t2` into my `t1` table. But I have some null values in `t2` table. When I try to insert the values:

```
Insert into t1 
   select * 
   from t2;
```

It throws this error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name',  table 'T1'; column does not allow nulls.

Is there any possibilities to set the default value to the column when we try to `insert` the `null` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Solution,

```
   insert into t1
    select id,isnull(name,'Peter') from t2
```

Second solution

```
ALTER TABLE T1 ALTER COLUMN name varchar(255) NULL

insert into t1
select id,name from t2

ALTER TABLE T1 ALTER COLUMN name varchar(255) NOT NULL
```

Comment: I am afraid the third solution fails if your column type is `uniqueidentifier` and the default is `(newid())`. It actually fails for all function calls in the `COLUMN_DEFAULT` regardless of datatype.

Answer (score 2):

So instead of

```
Insert into t1 select * from t2
```

you can rewrite your query as

```
Insert into t1 
select col1,col2, ISNULL(name, 'Peter'), othercolumns from t2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `COALESCE`

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO t1(Id, Name)
SELECT Id, COALESCE(Name, 'Peter') FROM t2;
```

Or you can use a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO t1(Id, Name)
SELECT Id, CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 'Peter' ELSE Name END
FROM t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query like:

`Insert into t1 select COALESCE(column1,'') from t2;`

For more details refer following link

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp